# Regex .net multiple line

Tags: c#, regex

I have these examples:

```
{I18n.get("Testing 123...")}

{I18n.get('Testing 123...')}

    {I18n.get(
            "Testing 123..."
     )}
    
    {I18n.get("Testing 123..."
     )}
    
    {I18n.get(
            "Testing 123...")}
```

I want to extract the 'Testing 123...' in .Net using C# Regex. What I did was:

```
        Regex r = new Regex(@"(?:I18n.get\(""(.+?)""\))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

        var matches = r.Matches(txt)
                        .Select(xx=> xx.Groups)
                        .Select(xx=> xx.Last().Value)
                        .ToList();
```

When is single line works perfect, but when is multiple line it fails...

And how would be possible to match in a single Regex when the txt is with double quotes " or when is with single quotes ' ?

Comment: You need to match whitespace, `@"I18n\.get\(\s*""(.+?)""\)"`. Also, you do not need two `Select`, just use `r.Matches(txt).Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Groups[1].Value).ToList()`

Comment: This way it grabs more than have to.. looks like is not finding the end  )...

Comment: Ok, add `\s*` on the right, `@"I18n\.get\(\s*""(.*?)""\s*\)"`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gktnTc/1).

Comment: Perfect! did a .Net exemple but you answered first https://dotnetfiddle.net/glGGvF . How about capture when its in Double Quotes and when is in Single Quotes.. would be possible in one regex? Make an answer so I can accept. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var r = new Regex(@"I18n\.get\(\s*(""|')(.*?)\1\s*\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
var results = r.Matches(txt).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[2].Value).ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=I18n%5c.get%5c%28%5cs*%28%22%7c%27%29%28.*%3f%29%5c1%5cs*%5c%29&i=%7bI18n.get%28%22Testing+123...%22%29%7d%0d%0a%7bI18n.get%28%22Testing+%5c%22123%5c%22%27.%27..%22%29%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a%7bI18n.get%28%27Testing+123...%27%29%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a++++%7bI18n.get%28%0d%0a++++++++++++%22Testing+123...%22%0d%0a+++++%29%7d%0d%0a++++%0d%0a++++%7bI18n.get%28%22Testing+123...%22%0d%0a+++++%29%7d%0d%0a++++%0d%0a++++%7bI18n.get%28%0d%0a++++++++++++%22Testing+123...%22%29%7d&o=is).

**Details**

- `I18n\.get\(` - a literal `I18n.get(` text
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `("|')` - Group 1: `"` or `'`
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any char, 0 or more occurrences, as few as possible
- `\1` - same value as captured in Group 1
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Not working Wiktor... https://dotnetfiddle.net/2WAFVX

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR Because you are not using my code. The value you need is in Group 2: `Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);`

Answer (score 0):

I contend it doesn't matter which open/close quotes should be in the regex when you  don't intend to actually parse it as a quoted string, right ?
I mean with all the embed escapes etc...

Use what you know as the delimiters, the text literals
`I18n.get(` stuff here `)`

You could use a sub validation that there's an inner quote, but since you're
not parsing quotes, it's not going to be strictly valid anyway.
Here, we just use it to *trim* so it's not matched and be part of element.

Here it is, the whole match is the value you're looking for, toss it into an array.

`@"(?s)(?<=I18n\s*\.\s*get\s*\(\s*['""]\s*).*?(?=\s*['""]\s*\))"`